# Getting a function's return type in Swift

Tags: swift, reflection, xcode6.3, ios8.3

I realize that reflection isn't fully supported (yet) in Swift, but reflection run time methods are (apparently) supported. I'm trying to get the return type of a function at run time. Here's my example

```
let s:Selector = "willAnimateRotation"
var m:Method = class_getInstanceMethod(object_getClass(self),  s)
let returnType = method_copyReturnType(m)
println("method: \(m); returnType: \(returnType)")
free(returnType)
```

Here's an example of my willAnimateRotation method, currently returning String:

```
private func willAnimateRotation() -> String {
    return "abc"
}
```

The output of this does not seem to vary depending on the return type of the selector. E.g., with String or Void return type for the selector, I get the following output:

> method: 0x0000000000000000; returnType: 0x0000000000000000

Thoughts?

ALSO: I'm actually not really trying to do this in Swift. I'm bridging an Objective-C class to Swift, and am getting the same results there, when the Objective-C code attempts to determine the return type of a Swift selector. That is, my end-goal in this case happens to be to use Objective-C to get the return type of a Swift selector.

Comment: @banana-- I realize that. That's not my question. My question is, using reflection, how do you, at run time, determine the return type.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I've figured this out. The problem comes with my use of the "private" keyword. If you drop that and just use:

```
func willAnimateRotation() -> String {
    return "abc"
}
```

The sample code above works fine.

Answer (score -1):

In Swift you indicate the function’s return type with the return arrow -> (a hyphen followed by a right angle bracket), which is followed by the name of the type to return.